# Pre-fill parameters in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Is there any way to pre-fill parameters in SQL Server Management Studio?

For example, when user right-clicks >> execute SP the parameters will be given in a drop-down menu.

Kind of similar to the parameters in SSRS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible, there's nowhere to save them. But you can fill the parameters manually, execute the stored procedure and save the generated script as a .SQL file. This way you will have a saved call to the SP with prefilled parameters.